Error when import tqdm while already installing the tqdm package
Here is my problem:

Import "tqdm" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource

I am using Python 3.13
I have installed the tqdm package, here is the pip list:

And some of the interpreters:

When I run my python file via cmd it doesn't work:

